# API Google Place Photos filter by place owner

Tags: php, google-api, google-places-api, google-places

How to get OWNER's photos of some place? Getting details by place id returns completely different results rather than:
https://www.google.com.ua/maps/place/CLOSER/@50.4660646,30.4977137,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x40d4ce6de5b089fd:0x8f001484c67a08e!8m2!3d50.4660612!4d30.4999077?hl=ru&shorturl=1
Here is cover image and another professional photos... but in details... only amateur photos made by onlookers nearby :)

Any idea how to filter photo results? Thank you.